# I can not get the correct series solution for this differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = x + y,\, y(0) = 1$

Let $\phi(x)$ be a solution to this equation. Then

$\phi(x) = 1 + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} \big(t + \phi(t)\big)\, dt$

Note : $\phi(0) = 1$ and $\phi'(x) = x + \phi(x)$.

Let $y_{0}(x) = 1$. Then $y_{n+1}(x) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} \big(t + y_{n}(t)\big)\, dt$

Okay so I want to show that the solutions I get will actually build up the series for $e^{x}$. Here is the problem I am having. $y_{1}(x) = 1 + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} (t + 1) dt = 1 + x + \displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2}$. Looks good, however, when I do $y_{2}(x)$ I get $1 + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} (t + 1 + t + \displaystyle\frac{t^2}{2})dt$. Integrating this does not give me something that looks to be $e^{x}$ because we get an $x^2$. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The differential equation for $e^x$ is $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$, try the same process with that if you want to build up the series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y$ is **not** $e^x$ but 
$$
y(x) = 2 e^x -x -1
$$
So after the first two terms (constant and $x$) the rest will the expansion of $e^x$ as you correctly noticed.

Here is what I got

$$y(x)=1+x+x^2+{{x^3}\over{3}}+{{x^4}\over{12}}+{{x^5}\over{60}}+\cdots $$

Compare this with
$$2\,e^{x}=2+2\,x+x^2+{{x^3}\over{3}}+{{x^4}\over{12}}+{{x^5}\over{60
 }}+\cdots $$

Comment: Ya that is what I was getting as well. I figured that my solution was incorrect since I found the problem in a book, but I guess books can have typos.